# variance of multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-variance

Assume $A_{kj} \sim$Multinomial$(1, \;\underbrace{(1/m, 1/m, ..., 1/m)}_{\textrm{m times}})$, where $k=1,2, ... m$ and $j=1,2, ... n$. It is clear to see that $\sum_{k=1}^mA_{kj}=1$. If we impose a restriction that $\sum_{j=1}^nA_{kj}=q$, for a discrete $q$ with $1\le q\le n$, then what is the variance of $A_{kj}$?

Comment: So if $A$ is the matrix you described is it correct that you are assuming that each row is multinomially distributed? Are the rows independent of each other?

Comment: @bdeonovic yes, $\mathbf A$ is a matrix with  each column from Mult distribution. The columns are supposed to be independent but because of the restriction, I think we can not assume independence